# Graph and macOS compatibility

Tags: cosmicmind

I'm currently working on an app on both iOS and macOS platforms.
Material and Graph are really saving me time. I'd like to know if Graph works on both iOS and macOS (with iCloud)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Graph is available for both `macOS` and `iOS` :) Use the `macOS` target when building.

Comment: Thank you! In that case, I'd build my Mac app with graph as well.

Comment: Nice :) If you have any questions, feel free to ask. All the best!